# Pixel manipulation with HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Ok so I am making a sketch app. There are two canvases-- one is a background image and the other an overlay that the user can draw on. I am trying to implement an eraser functionality that will "erase" any paths that the user has drawn on the overlay. So far my erase function looks like this:

```
function eraseCanvas(bottomCtx, topCtx, x, y, strokeWidth) {
            var bottomPixels = bottomCtx.getImageData(x, y, strokeWidth, strokeWidth);
            var topPixels = topCtx.getImageData(x, y, strokeWidth, strokeWidth);

            for (var i = 0; i < topPixels.data.length; i += 4) {
                topPixels.data[i] = bottomPixels.data[i];
                topPixels.data[i + 1] = bottomPixels.data[i + 1];
                topPixels.data[i + 2] = bottomPixels.data[i + 2];
                topPixels.data[i + 3] = bottomPixels.data[i + 3];
            }
            topCtx.putImageData(topPixels, x, y);
        }
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is erase pixels on the overlay by rewriting them using pixels from the background but it is not working. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not simplify your method by copying the pixel block from the bottom context, directly to the top context, using the [`dirtyWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData#Parameters) and [`dirtyHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData#Parameters) arguments as follows?

```
function eraseCanvas(bottomCtx, topCtx, x, y, strokeWidth) {

    var bottomPixels = bottomCtx.getImageData(x, y, strokeWidth, strokeWidth);

    // Directly draw bottomPixels from bottomCtx into topCtx, at the 
    // x,y coordinates, with 0,0 offset, between dimensions of 
    // strokeWidth x strongWidth 
    topCtx.putImageData(bottomPixels, x, y, 0, 0, strokeWidth, strokeWidth);
}
```

The [MDN documentation for `putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) offers further information about the `dirtyWidth`  and `dirtyHeight` arguments that I am referring to

Comment: I've come to discover that my function works correctly also, I just kept redrawing the path like an idiot afterwards however you showed me a much cleaner way of coding my function so thank you.